# False positive MS_PKGPROTECT bug in FindBugs

Tags: java, findbugs

I am pretty sure I am getting a false positive from FindBugs. My code is the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    protected static String fileNamePrefix;
}
```

And this is the bug I'm getting:

> Field should be package protected
>
> A mutable static field could be changed by malicious code or by accident. The field could be made package protected to avoid this vulnerability.
>
> Bug kind and pattern: MS - MS_PKGPROTECT

Is this really a false positive or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protected modifier allows a 3rd party subclass elevated access to the field by accident.

```
class MyAccidentSubClass extends MyClass {
    static {
        fileNamePrefix = "../" + fileNamePrefix;
    }
}
```

FindBugs is pointing out that 'protected' doesn't protect the field from accidental public access in the wild.  If the field was package protected then we know the intent is to share some secret among trusted friends.

In general, hide the field and create accessor methods as it is more flexible in terms of encapsulation, thread-safety, and lazy loading.

Comment: Wow didn't see that one coming... so creating a getter and setter for the field is the right way to proceed, right? should these two methods be protected or public?

Comment: @randombee Right.  The same rules apply to the field apply to the static method.  The difference with a method is that you can verify caller with something like the security manager.  If it is public data then make it public.  If it is some secret among your classes then make it default access.

Comment: One note on the FindBugs description. While the field can be changed "by accident", the fix will certainly not prevent malicious code. I can create my package in same package space, for e.g. org.apache.http.MyClass and access the flag. And if that didn't work, there's always reflection.